# Seeking mechanism to convert Delphi 7 CLX programs to Delphi XE6 - best option?

Tags: delphi-7, delphi-xe6, clx

We've been using Delphi 7 for our in-house development environment for several years now, and we're looking into updating to the newest version of Delphi.  (At the time, this appears to be XE6.)  However, many of the old programs we maintain were originally written in the Delphi 7 CLX environment, and I'm worried that we won't be able to keep maintaining them once we've set up XE6.

I know that there's always the option of just keeping the old compiler around on an old machine or a VM, but I'm thinking that as programs from XE6 go out, we'll be getting asked to add new functionality (from the new version) to those old programs as well.

Because of all of this, I'm trying to find information on either the proper way to, or else the best tool for, converting programs explicitly written in the CLX environment into a form that XE6 can handle.  What is/are the best option(s) for doing this?

Comment: For the most part, you can just remove the `Q` from the unit names in the `uses` clause (eg., `QDialogs` becomes `Dialogs`). You'll also have to deal with the change that was made in D2009 from ANSI characters and strings to Unicode (wide) characters and strings as the default string type, and any code that depends on a `Char` being a single byte in size (all of which has been discussed previously). (Your request for a recommendation for the "best tool" is off-topic here; we don't allow tool or library recommendations or requests to locate links or downloads.)